# How can I limit the length of input that user can enter in the console?

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I am working on a program that displays a frame around the text while the program is operating
I want to limit this input via the console because if the user enters a long input, He will go over the frame and go to the next line and so on Spoiling the whole design of the frame. The frame goes fine through the program but in this case, it goes so bad.

I use the following code to take the input

```
char entered_name[15];
print(">");      
scanf("%s",entered_name);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To accomplish this, I think you will have to write your own `get_line` function that will call `getchar` repeatedly and keep track of the number of characters input. When the right end of the box is reached, further characters will be discarded andperhaps a beep will be generated, or someting like that.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I just use a usual scanf(); and store the input in a char string

Comment: The string you are reading can only hold one character. So you're overwriting other data on the stack when the user types more characters. (That's not related to your question but you need to fix it.)

Comment: @SGeorgiades I have tried `getchar()` but I also see the typing goes over the frame it just get me the first char of the input but display what user enter when typing.

Comment: This is OS-dependent.  Tell us what OS, compiler, etc, you are using.

Comment: Engineer-A, not possible with standard C and library.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, I'm guessing that you are on Windows (**MS - DOS**) environment, if that's the case you can use the [_getch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160) function from `conio.h`. And create a custom function to get input. Should look like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 15

char *getInput(void)
{
    int c = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    char *buff = NULL;

    buff = calloc(0, MAX); /* you don't need to NULL terminate */

    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        /* handle oom */
    }

    while ((c = _getch()) != EOF && i < 15 && c != '\r') /* note \r insted of \n since we are on MS-DOS */
    {
        if (isalpha(c)) /* since you are asking for last name, check if its a letter */
        {
            putchar(c);
            buff[i++] = (char)c;
        }
    }

    return buff; /* don't forget to free */
}
```

Comment: "guessing that you are on Windows (MS - DOS) environment'  --> a reasonable guess.  Hope you are correct, even better if OP stated OS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
char *get_line(int maxline)
{
    bool done = FALSE;
    char *buffer = calloc(maxline + 1,sizeof(char));
    char chr;
    int idx = 0;

    while (!done) {
        if ((chr = getchar()) == EOF)
            done = TRUE;
        else if (isgraph(chr)) {
            if (idx < maxline)
                buffer[idx++] = chr;
            else printf("\b \b\a");
        } else if (chr == 8) {
            if (idx > 0) {
                printf(" \b");
                buffer[--idx] = 0;
            }
        } else if (chr == 10  ||  chr == 13) {
            putchar(chr == 13 ? 10 : 13);
            done = TRUE;
        }
    }
    buffer[idx] = 0;
    return buffer;
}
```

Where the argument `maxline` is the limit of how long the input may be, which should be the width of the window, less the length of the prompt, and one space at the end of the line.

Comment: `char chr; ... (chr = getchar()) == EOF` never true when `char` is _unsigned_.